# Salary Adjustment

Tags: professionalism

I am an accountant in a company and I have relocated 6 months before from Saudi to Dubai and I didn't know the cost of living in Dubai. Now I feel that I am underpaid and my colleges are getting more than me for the same position even my Junior salary is almost equal to mine.

Now I don't know how I can ask for the salary adjustment. Moreover, during this tenure I have improved many things.

Comment: Critical piece of information: did you move at the request of the company? @ duplicate voters: this question needs some cleanup but I'd say the details are different enough from the suggested duplicate that they're separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a mistake. Or they did not give you a hike as you are in the same role as before (happens with negligent/starter HR's).

So, you can talk to your manager and/or the HR person at the previous office and the current office, and inform them that the cost of living is higher, and you would like to have a salary adjustment with respect to the same.